# Ubuntu 13.04 boots to busybox exit doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, busybox

I turned on my computer and I was sent to the busybox. I have not done anything to my computer and it worked fine last night. I tried typing exit and then pressing enter and it gives me an alert that says /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk does not exist. I don't know how to fix this can anyone help? Like I said it worked fine last night and when I turned it on today it gave me this.

My computer is a dell studio xps that has dual boot to windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with Ubuntu live CD or live USB, assuming you have one, and see if you can even mount the main Ubuntu partition on your hard drive. If you can, unmount it.

Now install GSmartControl on the live CD/live USB. Start up GSmartControl after install and look at the S.M.A.R.T. attributes of your hard drive.

If nothing highlighted in pink for your HDD, that's good. The drive probably isn't failing.

Next, you can run `e2fsck` on the `/` partition of your hard drive. Maybe there's some corruption you can clean up. You want the partition not mounted before running this. Go into a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run `sudo fdisk -l` to find out which partition it is if you aren't sure. Then (let's assume it's `/dev/sda1`) type:

`sudo e2fsck /dev/sda1`

and see if it's not clean - and maybe it will fix some stuff. If there is serious corruption, you may be asked to fix a lot of stuff. There's an option in `e2fsck` to say 'yes to everything' - but if you get that many problems, you probably won't be booting this thing again, anyway.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112153.